# set encoding for reading text files into tm Corpora

Tags: text, encoding, text-mining, tm, corpus

loading a bunch of documents using tm Corpus i need to specify encoding.

All documents are UTF-8 encoded. If openend via text editor content is ok but corpus contents is full of strange symbols (indicioâ., ‘sœs....)
Source text is in spanish. ES_es

```
library(tm)
cname <- file.path("C:", "Users", "john", "Documents", "texts")
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname), encoding ="UTF-8")

> Error in Corpus(DirSource(cname), encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  unused argument (encoding = "UTF-8")
```

EDITED:

Getting  str(documents[1])  from corpus I've noticed:

.. ..$ language     : chr "en"

How can I specify, for instance "UTF-8", "Latin1" or any other encoding to avoid strange symbols?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean with "strange" - erroneous symbols or symbols you want to have converted to plain text (ASCII) without accents?

Comment: The strange symbols seems to be accented words and such. Converting to ANSI could work. Latin too.

Comment: Somewhere else I saw `Encoding(data) <- "UTF-8"`, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920396/r-corpus-is-messing-up-my-utf-8-encoded-text

Comment: language     > chr "en"  if I get on console      str(docs[1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the "C:" it's clear you are using Windows, which assumes a Windows-1252 encoding (on most systems) rather than UTF-8.  You could try reading the files in as character and then setting `Encoding(myCharVector) <- "UTF-8"`.  If the input encoding was UTF-8 this should cause your system to recognise and display the UTF-8 characters properly.

Alternatively this will work, although it also makes **tm** unnecessary:

```
require(quanteda)
docs <- corpus(textfile("C:/Users/john/Documents/texts/*.txt", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Then you can see the texts using for example:

```
cat(texts(docs)[1:2])
```

They should have the encoding bit set and display properly.  Then if you prefer, you can get these into **tm** using:

```
docsTM <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts(docs)))
```

Comment: It's hard for me tiding nose exactly without your files, but the basic approach should work. I'm happy to try it with your files if you send a link to a few of them.

Comment: Hi ken, an issue arised: dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docsTM)           Error: inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE

Comment: Quanteda has an equivalent command dfm() btw that works directly on docs

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there's no need of using quanteda package (besides some odd behaviour losing file names when converting to TM VCorpora)

```
files <- DirSource(directory = "C:/Users/john/Documents/",encoding ="UTF-8" )
mycorpus<- VCorpus(x=files)
```

Now encoding is correct.

Comment: I am having this issue, i use `docs<- VCorpus(DirSource(directory = inputdir, encoding ="UTF-8"))`, and my txt files are saved with UTF-8 encoding, but i still get **<U+FB01>scal** instead of **fiscal** and **bene<U+FB01>t** instead of **benefit** in my DTM. Is there something i am doing worng?