# Odd symbols in R script lost after reloading

Tags: r, tm, topic-modeling, rscript, topicmodels

I am implementing an LDA topic model using `tm` and `topicmodels` packages. Some of the documents contain odd characters that are not removed automatically (e.g. `docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation` does not remove `’`. When I read the .txt files into R, the Euro sign €, for example, shows up as `â‚¬`. There are other odd characters throughout the corpus that show up frequently and need to be removed manually. Thus, I use the following lines to do it:

```
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "’")  
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "‐")  
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "–")  
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "â‚¬")  
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "â€™")
```

My problem is that once I close the R-script and reopen it, these odd symbols change. Instead of `’` the sript shows `'`, instead of `â€™` it shows `â???T`. As a result, the symbols are not removed from the text when I close and reopen the R-script and I have to manually change these symbols to what I need every-time the script is reopened. I copied these lines into a Word document and every time I reopen R-script I paste the lines from Word document into R-script. This is very inefficient. So I wonder is there a way for me to save the R-script so that these  odd symbols are not lost after reopening? Or maybe I should do something with my original .txt files? Thank you!

Comment: This is an encoding issue... when you defined your corpus, did you use `encoding='UTF-8'` as an argument? Here is more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278333/set-encoding-for-reading-text-files-into-tm-corpora

Comment: Also more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920396/r-corpus-is-messing-up-my-utf-8-encoded-text

Comment: If using `RStudio`, try reload with encoding and choose `UTF-8`

Comment: it depends on whether you are using windows or unix, and tm, in my experience, is very troublesome with encodings

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! It was indeed a coding issue. I used `files <- DirSource(directory = inputdir,encoding ="UTF-8" )
docs<- VCorpus(x=files)` to define the corpus and the odd symbols do not show up anymore, so i dont need to remove them. Now i am struggling with removing `’` at the end of multiple words... but I guess it is a different issue